# iOSOpenDev - app doesn't appear on a SpringBoard when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, jailbreak, cydia

I'm trying to run my app on a device (iPhone 5, 8.1.2) using XCode 6 and iOSOpenDev.

I configured everything using this [wiki](https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev) page. After building, copying and installing .deb package on the device (Cmd + Shift + i) I cannot find the icon of the app on a SpringBoard. However Cydia is able to see it installed. Also if I run the app with iOS Simulator it works just fine.

The app is a very simple navigation based application (simple user interface).

What could be the possible reasons for that? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: I've never worked with jailbreak stuff, but `.deb` is a Debian Linux package file. There's no reason that would ever run on iOS.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry @Linuxios, but this is not correct. It is a common way of packing apps for Jailbroken devices. You might want to check Google for that, or the wiki page I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I didn't realize they were using Debian packages for jailbreak. Sorry bout that!

Comment: Look into the `uicache` command.  You may need to run it after installing your app.  You should also explain how you're installing it.  Cydia?  SCP'ing the .deb file and installing at the command line with `dpkg`? Something else?  Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

I found out that it was a Cydia bug - not all the apps are shown on the SpringBoard. There are many tutorials on how to fix it. I followed [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehDug-nsZzU).

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but please don't simply provide a link to a youtube video.  In addition to it taking too much time for people to open the video and get through it all, this information is completely unsearchable.  Stack Overflow is a text-based answer site.  Copy the gist of the answer into your post here.  It's fine to link to the youtube video as a reference.